# Public site collection not found

Tags: site-collection, public-website

We just finished migrating our 2007 site/collections to SP Foundation 2013 and all urls, site collections, etc seemed to be working fine internally but once we opened the site to the public, we are unable to reach any of the site collections (Page does not exist). The main site works just fine though.

I have already enabled anonymous access to all of the site collections. Is there anything else i need to do?

internally

```
http://servername                         <-- this works
http://servername/facilities/somelocation <-- this works
```

externally

```
http://ourwebsite.com                         <-- works
http://ourwebsite.com/facilities/somelocation <-- does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out we forgot to add the internet AAM. Everything is coming up now.